# Limit time to execute a PHP line

Tags: php, timeout

I got a function to check if a URL is valid before putting it in my page, and I use
`$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_exec($ch);
$retcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);`
to do so. However, it recently happened that one external site wasn't working and was loading forever, reflecting that problem to my site as it got stuck at that last line of code, eventually ending in a timeout fatal error.
How can I tell the server to only try curl_getinfo for a couple of seconds, and just return false if it's taking too long? It doesn't have to return an uncatchable timeout error that will compromise my page instead of just hiding an URL.

Comment: Check the `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` options.

Comment: Great, I guess this does the job perfectly in my case, but I still wonder, is there any way to check how long any other PHP command is taking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php and use CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT.

Comment: So just adding `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 3);` should do the job, right? I can't replicate the problem so I don't know how to test it... What will curl_getinfo() return if it doesn't make it in time?

Comment: According to [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php), HTTP status should be 408="Request Timeout".  But probably anything other than a 200 and you want to handle it as error.